# Can Supply-Line Cranes supply themselves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Supply-Line Cranes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Supply-Line%20Cranes) enter the battlefield, put a +1/+1 counter on target creature.

Can the cranes target themselves?

Comment: Not only can you, that's the beauty of it! A 3/5 for 5 is totally playable in limited. And at worst, that's what this guy is. But if you have a character with deathtouch, doublestrike, or even just a small flier that you'd like to survive against other 1 and 2 power fliers, you can put that +1/+1 on him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is a valid target because it is on the battlefield when the trigger happens. What happens, in order:

- Supply-Line Cranes enters the battlefield.
- The game checks for any triggers that happen as a result of this event.
- Supply-Line Cranes' trigger is found, and it triggers.
- You put the trigger on the stack, and must choose a target at that time.
- Supply-Line Cranes is a creature (and it's on the battlefield) at this time, so it is a valid target for you to choose.
- When the trigger resolves, Supply-Line Cranes is still a valid target, so it resolves, putting the counter on Supply-Line Cranes.

The other answers are correct, but fail to mention that you must choose the target when the triggered ability goes on the stack, so it matters that it's a valid target when it triggers, not so much that it's a valid target when it resolves. (If it stopped being a valid target before it resolved, because it were destroyed with an instant or something, then the ability would be countered and go away. But it would still have been a valid/legal target in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

In this text, Target creature can be any creature, Supply-Line Cranes is a creature, and - quite rightly said above - is on the battlefield when the ability resolves.

If the word "another" was placed before target creature in this text, this would mean any creature bar Supply-Line Cranes.

Comment: It makes no difference who is on the battlefield when the ability resolves. What matters is that Supply-Line Cranes is on the battlefield when the ability triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The "When" phrase makes that a [triggered ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability), that triggers once the cranes are on the battlefield.  When it triggers, it is put on the stack.  When it resolves, the cranes are on the battlefield, and thus a legitimate target for the crane.

Comment: Not quite right. When the ability is put on the stack, it must have a valid target. The crane is on the battlefield, so it is valid.